# PyDev can't debug anymore

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm using eclipse 4.2.1 and pydev 2.7.1 (previously 2.6.0)

Everything was working fine, until suddenly the debugger stopped working - it prints "pydev debugger: starting" and then doesn't run the program at all, but just hangs.

Based on some information I found in other problem reports, I changed some debug constants (DEBUG_TRACE_LEVEL = 3 and DEBUG_TRACE_BREAKPOINTS = 3) and got this output now:

```
pydev debugger: starting
('Executing file ', '/path/to/my/program.py')
('arguments:', "['/path/to/my/program.py']")
('Connecting to ', '127.0.0.1', ':', '40972')
('Connected.',)
('received command ', '501\t1\t1.1')
sending cmd: CMD_VERSION 501    1   1.1

sending cmd: CMD_THREAD_CREATE 103  2   <xml><thread name="pydevd.reader" id="-1"/></xml>

sending cmd: CMD_THREAD_CREATE 103  4   <xml><thread name="pydevd.writer" id="-1"/></xml>
```

Nothing happens afterwards.

**Edit:** I created a new workspace and pydev seems to work there. Currently trying to find out which metadata folder is causing the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that removing .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources from the workspace solves the problem.. but it also removes all the projects so I had to reimport them.

Comment: What worked for me is that I deleted .history in that folder only. My debugger started to work again and I didn't lose my projects.