# Pydev Debugger not starting

Tags: python, pydev

I have tried to debug the project using the pydev however it only shows the message and does nothing more, anyone have any idea what may be happening?

ps.: he always ran regular .. now that started it

[image]

Comment: I had similar problem and updating eclipse and pydev solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved here:
[PyDev can't debug anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597812/pydev-cant-debug-anymore)
I just had the same problem, and it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and ended up **removing all breakpoints**, which solved the problem.

*Window* ➔ *Show View*. Find and open *Debug* ➔ *Breakpoints* and delete all Breakpoints.